# App Crash iPhone 5 and below

Tags: iphone, swift

I released a simple game which works fine on iPhone 5s, 6, 6s and iPads. But when running on iPhone 5, 5c, 4S or 4, the app crashes at the point when this code happens:

```
let delay = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(300)))*Int(NSEC_PER_SEC)/100
```

I get this error:

> thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

I think it's really weird it only happens on iPhone 5 and below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum value of a 32 bits integer is 2 147 483 647.

Your `delay` value may be greater than that, so sometimes it will crash on 32 bits platforms like these devices you listed because `Int` won't be able to hold the value.

Comment: Can be fixed by making it a UInt

Answer (score 3):

If the reason is because the Int cant hold the value then make it a `UInt`. This will double its maximum value.